# R - Take average of previous 4 rows and expand table

Tags: r

I have a table like :

```
Texas Colorado

3      1
4      2
3      3
4      4
```

I want to extend this table by 30 rows such that, each new row takes the average of the previous 4 rows. Expected output:

```
Texas Colorado

3     1
4     2
3     3
4     4
3.5   2.5
3.625 2.875
```

My main issue is I don't know how to dynamically create rows

Comment: I made these numbers up but this dataset is (seasonally adjusted) monthly unemployment rates covering the period
January 1976 through August 2010 for the 50 US states

Comment: It's not my area of expertise, but I have a nagging suspicion in the back of my mind that this problem should probably be approached using some sort of time-series forecast, maybe arima?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R you can do:

```
 Reduce(function(x,y)rbind(x,colMeans(tail(x,4))),1:30, init = df)
      Texas Colorado
1  3.000000 1.000000
2  4.000000 2.000000
3  3.000000 3.000000
4  4.000000 4.000000
5  3.500000 2.500000
6  3.625000 2.875000
7  3.531250 3.093750
8  3.664062 3.117188
9  3.580078 2.896484
10 3.600098 2.995605
11 3.593872 3.025757
...
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. Can I ask the logic of the code? I apologize as I'm new to programming.

Comment: the code is doing `df = colMeans(tail(df, 4))` repeating this 30 times. `tail(df,4)` just takes the last 4 rows of the dataframe. `colMeans()` computes the means. Now Reduce is a forloop that uses the previous result as an input of the current result. eg `Reduce("+",1:10)` simply means add 1+2 then add 3 to the result then add 4 etc.. to see what happens use `Reduce('+',1:10,accumulate=TRUE)` also you can do `?Reduce` to learn more about it. Then `rbind(a,b)` is used to bind rowwise

Comment: Understood. And what is the purpose of function(x,y) before the rbind? What is y in this case?

Comment: `Reduce` takes a function as the first argument. ie TRY `Reduce(function(x,y)x+y, 1:10, accumulate=TRUE)`. so in my case, y will give the number of times to run the function, ie 1:30 is my y

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rollmean` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
for(i in 1:30) df1 <- rbind(df1, rollmeanr(tail(df1, 4), k = 4))
df1
#      Texas Colorado
#1  3.000000 1.000000
#2  4.000000 2.000000
#3  3.000000 3.000000
#4  4.000000 4.000000
#5  3.500000 2.500000
#6  3.625000 2.875000
#7  3.531250 3.093750
#8  3.664062 3.117188
#9  3.580078 2.896484
#10 3.600098 2.995605
#11 3.593872 3.025757
#12 3.609528 3.008759
#13 3.595894 2.981651
#14 3.599848 3.002943
#15 3.599785 3.004777
#16 3.601264 2.999533
#17 3.599198 2.997226
#18 3.600024 3.001120
#19 3.600068 3.000664
#20 3.600138 2.999636
#21 3.599857 2.999661
#22 3.600022 3.000270
#23 3.600021 3.000058
#24 3.600009 2.999906
#25 3.599977 2.999974
#26 3.600007 3.000052
#27 3.600004 2.999997
#28 3.599999 2.999982
#29 3.599997 3.000001
#30 3.600002 3.000008
#31 3.600000 2.999997
#32 3.600000 2.999997
#33 3.600000 3.000001
#34 3.600000 3.000001
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
for(i in 1:2) {
              df1 <- df1 %>%
                        slice((n() - 3):n()) %>%
                        summarise_all(mean) %>%
                        bind_rows(df1, .)
 }
```

---

Or with `accumulate`

```
seq_len(30) %>%
    accumulate(.,  ~ .x %>% 
    slice(tail(row_number(), 4)) %>% 
    summarise_all(mean) %>%
    bind_rows(.x, .), .init = df1) %>%
    .[[30]]
#    Texas Colorado
#1  3.000000 1.000000
#2  4.000000 2.000000
#3  3.000000 3.000000
#4  4.000000 4.000000
#5  3.500000 2.500000
#6  3.625000 2.875000
#7  3.531250 3.093750
#8  3.664062 3.117188
#   ...
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Texas = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 4L), Colorado = 1:4), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -4L))
```

Comment: something is not right. while the last 4 rows of a column were 3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5, the additional row has value 6.2.

I'm sorry I'm new to programming to can't examine why it happened with reference to your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `while` and `colMeans` from R base.

```
while(nrow(df1)<=30){ 
  df1 <- rbind(df1, colMeans(tail(df1, 4)))
}
df1

       Texas Colorado
1  3.000000 1.000000
2  4.000000 2.000000
3  3.000000 3.000000
4  4.000000 4.000000
5  3.500000 2.500000
6  3.625000 2.875000
7  3.531250 3.093750
8  3.664062 3.117188
9  3.580078 2.896484
10 3.600098 2.995605
...
```

Comment: Thank you! Only that my df had 300 rows, so I had to modify (nrow(df1)<=30) to (nrow(df1)<=330). Can I ask I ask the logic of the rbind part?

Comment: Exactly!  you have to set ` (nrow(df1)<=330)`. The `rbind` part combines the existing with the roll mean result in each iteration.